# Difference "back"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, difference, conjunctions

What's the difference if you rearrange "back"? Or is it just grammatically incorrect?

> taking ***back*** my love
>
> taking my love ***back***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is idiomatic to say  to  take something back but take back something is also possible.

There is no difference in meaning.

> **taking my love back** is the idiomatic  usage.

I take back  what I have said earlier means I withdraw what I have said earlier.

I here with attach the link to make things clear.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-back